# How could I make a directory on a server inaccessible to the public by the url but accessible to php code on the same website?

Tags: php, cpanel

So I have www.mydomain.com

Under that domain I have a directory, lets call it www.mydomain.com/secrets

I have php scripts that access stuff in the /secrets directory (zip files mainly), how could I make all files in that directory still work with the php scripts but if someone went to www.mydomain.com/secrets/file.txt they wouldn't see the file.

Comment: problem with the dupe is its using legacy code

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Apache (I haven't seen an installation of PHP with cPanel that doesn't have it, but I might not be so worldly), then `.htaccess` file in the specific directory is a good bet.

Create a file named .htaccess inside the directory where you want to restrict public access, and give it the following contents:

**If on Apache 2.2**

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

**If on Apache 2.4**

```
Require all denied
```

Comment: is `Order`  required in this case?

Comment: Possibly not, force of habit

Comment: fair enough, simply curious, i cant see anything definitive in the docs, i could of course just test it :-)